# Summarizing a multi-dimensional distribution

Tags: distributions, computational-statistics, curve-fitting

I have an empirical distribution of observations along a number of dimensions. The dimensions are either categorical or ordinal (low frequency, equally spaced time steps from 0 to cut-off). At the moment there is no interdependence along the dimensions so clusters would be rare or uninformative (presumably some orderings of the categorical dimensions will generate peaks).

My problem is that I want to summarize this distribution into a fixed number of regions that represent the dimensions as good as possible. The goal is not to directly compress the description of the distribution so I don't foresee a limit to the description of the regions, I'm mostly interested in subdividing the curve in a number of representative regions).

Ideally the regions will be convex but this is not a hard requirement.

For example, if the number of regions is set to 1, the region would be the entire support and be the average of the density.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned time, so did you de-seasonalize, de-trend, or assess auto-correlation?  Try running K-means cluster analysis on the objects.  If you want to split the objects into two groups, then set $K=2$, three groups, $K=3$, etc. K-means won't compress, it will inform you which objects are similar within each of the $K$ groups.  To identify what value of $K$ is optimal, you need to use cluster validity (analysis), preferably the cross-validation type and not the silhouette index, Davies-Bouldin index, or Dunn's index (however, these are good starting approximations).  Indeed, hierarchical clustering is not what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've now clarified in the question that the ordinals go from 0 to cut-off so I didn't de-trend or de-seasonalize but also don't want to. We've considered K-means but I understand that looks mainly for clusters which would not expect in this data set. Along the ordinal dimensions I expect only one peak (exactly one change in the sign of the derivative).

Comment: Ok, your post sounded like an unsupervised knowledge discovery problem, for which you are trying to learn about data.  However, you keep referring to what sounds like a "function" and "derivatives", so you should couch something like this as a "function approximation" (curve-fitting) problem and not a data learning-separation problem.   Perhaps knot-based regression, partial least squares, or a Parzen-window approach may help.